# How to prevent opening my website with ip

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to configure apache web server to prevent opening my website by ip address.
For example if my website is "domain.com" and my server ip is "111.222.333.444", you should not open my website by entering "111.222.333.444".
How can I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe by checking the `HTTP_HOST` request header …?

Comment: Just FYI "111.222.333.444" is an invalid IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block request by IP address
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.222\.333\.444$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: @anubhva, I want to disallow user from Russia to access my website?
and my website is deployed on heroku server so could you please help me.